# Virtualizing an ISP WAN Connection

Tags: networking, ip, routing, hardware-virtualization

If an ISP offers one WAN connection, and any additional WAN connections would incur extra fees as well as wiring another port and such, how could they track a virtual IP?

For background information, there is no modem accessible. The network is setup by the ISP for an apartment complex with an individual WAN connection to every room.

Assuming the ISP uses DHCP, which it is believed they do, what would stop someone from creating a vSwitch and connecting 2 VM's to separate virtual WAN's with different external IP's? Would this method even work? If so how would an ISP prevent everyone from doing it?

Comment: Your ISP is likely using [Carrier Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) so what you propose wouldn't work.

Comment: @DavidPostill I wouldn't think so because I am able to host any and all services I'd like without issue. Also my external IP does not follow RFC 1918, it is a public address.